Как в webview2 Заполнить поле типа file?
Много лет назад был найден способ заполнения полей type="file" еще для webbrowser.
async Task PopulateInputFile_poster(string file_poster)
        {
            ExecuteScript("document.getElementById(\"fln1\").focus();");

            // delay the execution of SendKey to let the Choose File dialog show up
            var sendKeyTask = Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith((_) =>
            {
                // this gets executed when the dialog is visible
                SendKeys.Send(disk + "" + "poster.webp" + "{ENTER}");
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

            ExecuteScript("document.getElementById(\"fln1\").click();"); // this shows up the dialog

            await sendKeyTask;

            // delay continuation to let the Choose File dialog hide
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }


        async Task Populate()
        {
            ExecuteScript("document.getElementById(\"fln1\").focus();");
            await PopulateInputFile_poster("fln1");
        }

И потом все это вызывается при нажатии нужной кнопки:
Populate().ContinueWith((_) =>
            {

            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

Этот способ работает и для webview2. Но меня интересует есть ли какая-нибудь альтернатива? Т.к. в приведенном мною примере заполняется лишь одно поле, но у меня есть парочка проектов, где таких полей больше 10. Их заполнение занимает некоторое время, и его хотелось бы сократить, если это возможно)

А какой смысл заполнять поля, если можно (и нужно!) отправлять сразу нужный запрос нужного типа, с нужными данными, на нужный адрес...?

Средствами JS никак не заполнить. Выбор файла пользователем разрешает браузеру доступ к файлу. Если бы скрипты могли делать то же самое, грубо говоря у любого сайта был бы прямой доступ к диску вашего компьютера. Поэтому только вручную. Либо как написано в комментарии выше, отправлять POST запрос на сервер напрямую.

Если все работает сокращайте Task.Delay(1000) так как для 10 полей будет 10 секунд что не очень
